# Who I've sold your cats *are/is* those people

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I have already posted questions about wh-cleft verb agreement, but after having watched all the links you'd graciously provided, I was able to find no answer that'd explain which verb to use in this example.

1. Who I've sold your cats *are* those people
2. Who I've sold your cats *is* those people.

Comment: Unfortunately, the examples are so far from idiomatic that they are wrong and unsalvageable without rewriting.

Comment: The noun *people* is plural, so the verb must be plural: “Those people **who** bought the cats **are / were** very trustworthy” is perfectly grammatical.

Answer (score 3):

According to *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p1422) the relative lexeme *who* cannot be used in what it calls *pseudo-clefts* (also known as *wh-clefts*). So, the CGEL would claim that neither of your alternative sentences is acceptable.

This is the relevant extract from the CGEL's section on pseudo-clefts:

> *Range of relative lexemes*
>
> Not all relative lexemes are permitted in fused relatives, and hence
> in pseudo-clefts. Most importantly, **who** is excluded:
>
> [30] *Who achieved the best result was Angela.
>
> Instead we need an *it-cleft* (*It was Angela who achieved the best
> result*) or some other specifying clause (such as *The one who
> achieved the best result was Angela*.)

On this basis, your sentence could be rewritten as

> It was those people to whom I've sold your cats.

This avoids the concord problem in your question.

---

Note that the star in **Who achieved the best result was Angela* indicates ungrammaticality in the CGEL.

Comment: Does it mean that I can also say, "The ones whom I've sold your cats to are those people"?

Comment: Yes, but if you are using the formal _whom_ it is probably more consistent to pied-pipe _to_, i.e. _"The ones to whom I've sold your cats are those people_". In conversational English you could say: "_The ones I've sold your cats to are those people_."

Comment: Also, 'It was those people whom I've sold/given your cats' (modelling on 'I've sold/given those people your cats') are ungrammatical.